# I made a quiz in android studio and i want to show only 15 questions but i have 100 in total? I have SQLite but i don't understand how it works

Tags: java, android-studio

I made a quiz with SQLite but its confusing and i can't understand how to store questions inside code as i want to show only 15 questions but i want to have 100 questions in total.

I tried storing them with SQLite but i just can't understand how it works.

private SQLiteDatabase db;

```
public QuizDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    this.db = db;

    final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION4 + " TEXT, " +
            QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER"  +
            ")";

    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
    fillQuestionsTable();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
private void fillQuestionsTable(){
    Question q1 = new Question("Who almost killed Thanos in the Final Battle?",
            "Captain America", "Iron Man", "Captain America", "Scarlet Witch",4);
    addQuestion(q1); etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room +paging lib will be right choice for you.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-architecture-components-using-the-paging-library-with-room--cms-31535

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

Comment: Thanks for answering do you perhaps know where i can learn the code similar to mine, is there a video turtorial or a website.

Comment: Glad to help you.